# I am getting InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value

Tags: javascript, c#, html

**I have tried every StackOverflow solution that can be related to "error:js?sensor=false:71 InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value" the problem persists,**
This is my Javascript code, The error in console doesnt specify the line.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        
        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            //  marker:true
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {

                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">
```

And Here is my controller

```
public partial class LocationMapTest_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

    }
    public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Title FROM Article", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }

            rows.Add(row);
           //Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows).ToString());

        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like asp.net core. This looks like web forms which was never offered in asp.net core.